# List inside JSON Powershell

Tags: json, powershell

I am trying to parse the following JSON into a PSCustomObject

```json
[
  {
    "tags": [
      {
        "tagName": "Microsoft Teams"
      },
      {
        "tagName": "Worldwide (Standard Multi-Tenant)"
      },
      {
        "tagName": "General Availability"
      },
      {
        "tagName": "Web"
      },
      {
        "tagName": "Desktop"
      }
    ],
    "tagsContainer": {
      "products": [
        {
          "tagName": "Microsoft Teams"
        }
      ],
      "cloudInstances": [
        {
          "tagName": "Worldwide (Standard Multi-Tenant)"
        }
      ],
      "releasePhase": [
        {
          "tagName": "General Availability"
        }
      ],
      "platforms": [
        {
          "tagName": "Web"
        },
        {
          "tagName": "Desktop"
        }
      ]
    },
    "id": 51230,
    "title": "Microsoft Teams: New file sharing experience",
    "description": "Streamline sharing with Microsoft Teams. You can now create a shareable link for any file stored in Teams and directly set the appropriate permissions. Additionally, you can also set permissions for files stored in SharePoint or OneDrive while composing a private chat or starting a channel conversation.",
    "status": "Launched",
    "moreInfoLink": "https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-sharepoint-blog/rich-new-file-and-sharing-experiences-throughout-microsoft-365/ba-p/960129",
    "publicRoadmapStatus": "Include this month",
    "created": "2019-05-08T07:00:00",
    "modified": "2022-01-13T00:05:19.663",
    "publicDisclosureAvailabilityDate": "March CY2021",
    "publicPreviewDate": ""
  }
]
```

I have that JSON stored in a variable like this:

```
$RoadmapContent = Get-Content -Raw -Path ".\M365Roadmap_single.json" | ConvertFrom-Json
```

And this would be my PSCustomObject:

```
$RoadmapItems =[PSCustomObject]@{
        Title = $($RoadmapContent.title)
        Tags = $($RoadmapContent.tags)
}
```

I would like to have this tags in a single column, like this: Microsoft Teams, Worldwide (Standard Multi-Tenant), General Availability, Web, Desktop

I have tried to accomplish that (unsuccessfully) like this:

```
$RoadmapContent.Tags -join ";"
```

How can I parse this?

Many thanks!

Edit:

I can access the tags like this:

```
foreach ($tag in $RoadmapContent.tags) {Write-Host $Tag.tagName}
```

But cannot figure out how to use this in a PSCustomObject

Comment: If I understood correctly you may be looking for `Get-Content ... | ConvertFrom ... | Select-Object *, @{ N='Tags'; E={ $_.tags.tagname -join ', '}} -ExcludeProperty tags`

Comment: I swear I have done the .tags.tagname thing a million times and it has not worked for me, but having done that, it works. Will post a solution, thanks a lot @SantiagoSquarzon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out thanks to a comment in the original question, here's the full code:

```
$RoadmapContent = Get-Content -Raw -Path ".\M365Roadmap_single.json" | ConvertFrom-Json 

$RoadmapItems =[PSCustomObject]@{
        Title = $($RoadmapContent.title)
        Tags = $($RoadmapContent.tags.tagname -join ', ')
}

$RoadmapItems
```